# Problems with libftdi and libusb

Tags: macos, libusb

I'm running on a Macbook, OS X 10.6.4.  I've installed the latest version of libusb 1.x and also libusb-compat.  The example applications in libusb compile and run, no problems there so I am assuming that it's installed correctly.  Libftdi also appears to install correctly, but it seems to be having trouble with libusb.  I tried one of the example apps and I get this error message:

```
$ ./simple
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _usb_init
  Referenced from: /Users/Me/Downloads/libftdi-0.19/src/.libs/libftdi.1.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _usb_init
  Referenced from: /Users/Me/Downloads/libftdi-0.19/src/.libs/libftdi.1.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap
```

The assumption that libusb is to blame is because _usb_init is a libusb function, I found a post here that was along the same lines http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/11/11/ruby-usb-libusb/ but for Ruby.

Trying to get things going with Pylibftdi,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blah/list_devices.py", line 4, in <module>
    for device in Driver().list_devices():
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pylibftdi/driver.py", line 61, in __init__
    fdll = CDLL(ftdi_lib)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 345, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libftdi.dylib, 6): Symbol not found: _usb_bulk_read
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libftdi.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/libftdi.dylib
```

Note that to get anything to even run using Pyftdi I had to install libftdi for i386 rather than x86_64 as default (throws up mach-o errors) - however, even installing libftdi 'normally' gives the OSErrors above.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with libftdi 0.19 you're supposed to use libusb 0.1 (atleast according to thier web page. http://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/download.php).  There's a port of libftdi out there to use libusb 1.0 if you want.  I've been using it for SYNC and ASYNC Fifos and its been working great.

http://developer.intra2net.com/git/?p=libftdi-1.0

git://developer.intra2net.com/libftdi-1.0

Good luck

Comment: Hi, apologies for the very late reply - I did eventually get this working.  I think I ended up installing multiple copies of libusb which fouled everything up.  What did work was using the installer for the AVR toolchain (which includes libusb) and then installing libftdi on top of that.

Thanks for the link though, I'll look into it.